# Given the function $f$ defined by $f(x, y) = xe^{y} + 1$ develop into a Taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Given the function $f$ defined by $f(x, y) = xe^{y} + 1$:

Develop $f$ into a Taylor series around the point $(1, 0)$

I know how to develop around $(0, 0)$:

$T(x, y) = 1 + x\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{y^k}{k!}$

ChatGPT suggests that around $(1, 0)$ is:

$T(x, y) = 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{y^k}{k!} + (x - 1)\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \frac{y^l}{l!}$

I don't understand where the middle term $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{y^k}{k!}$ comes from.

Also, I would like to determine $\frac{\partial^{10} f}{\partial x^4 \partial y^6} (1, 0) $ and $ \frac{\partial^{12} f}{\partial x \partial y^{11}} (1, 0) $ using the Taylor series, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: $f(1+h,k)=(1+h)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{k^n}{n!}+1$ and $\frac{\partial^{p+q} f}{\partial x^p\partial y^q} (1, 0)$ is the coefficient of $h^pk^q.$ Note that it is $0$ if $p\ge2.$

Comment: If you use $x=1+(x-1)$ in your $(0,0)$ expansion, you obtain the one by ChatGPT.

Answer (score 2):

Let's recall that the Taylor series of a bivariate function around a point $(x_0,y_0)$ is given by
$$
f(x,y) = \sum_{n,m\ge0} \left.\frac{\partial^{n+m}f}{\partial x^n \partial y^m}\right|_{(x_0,y_0)} \frac{(x-x_0)^n}{n!} \frac{(y-y_0)^m}{m!}.
$$
Now, since $f(x,y) = xe^y + 1$, hence $\partial_x f(x,y) = e^y$ and $\partial_y f(x,y) = xe^y$, one understands that all the higher-order derivatives with respect to $x$ will be zero; in consequence, the index $n$ can only take the values $0$ and $1$. The remaining partial derivatives can be thus computed straightforwardly; indeed, one has $\partial_y^m f(x,y) = xe^y$ and $\partial_x \partial_y^m f(x,y) = \partial_y^m e^y = e^y$, hence finally
$$
\frac{\partial^{n+m}f}{\partial x^n \partial y^m} = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
   xe^y + 1 & \mathrm{if}\; n = m = 0 \\
   xe^y & \mathrm{if}\; n=0 \;\mathrm{and}\; m > 0 \\
    e^y & \mathrm{if}\; n=1 \;\mathrm{and}\; m > 0 \\
      0 & \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.,
$$
which you still need to evaluate at $(1,0)$.

Comment: I am stuck at the case $n=m=0$.

Comment: @BobDobbs   The $0^\mathrm{th}$ derivative is nothing else than the original function, i.e. $f^{(0,0)}(x,y) = f(x,y) = xe^y + 1$. In consequence, the constant term of the Taylor expansion is given by $f(1,0) = 2$.

Comment: İ know and I also calculated 2. But you wrote at the end hence finally... How do we get the 2 there?

Comment: @BobDobbs  Oh my bad, you're right ! I forgot to precise that the above formula is valid for $(n,m) \neq (0,0)$. It is now corrected.

Comment: @Abezhko Better now. But, nobody's perfect. +1

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{\partial^{p+q} f}{\partial x^p\partial y^q} (1, 0)$ is $p!q!$ times the coefficient of $h^pk^q$ in
$$f(1+h,k)=(1+h)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{k^n}{n!}+1.$$
It is therefore $0$ if $p\ge2,$ and
$$\frac{\partial^qf}{\partial y^q} (1, 0)=\frac{\partial^{1+q} f}{\partial x\partial y^q} (1, 0)=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

We can write $f(x, y) = x e^y + 1 = (x - 1)e^y + e^y + 1$, and then expand the Taylor series of $e^y$ to get the expression from ChatGPT.

To extract the $(m, n)$-th partial derivative from the series, you just have to look for the corresponding $(x - 1)^m y^n$ term.